# Almost illegal termination

Tags: discrimination

From another website: A is autistic but has always done a good job. The company gets a new manager M who hates autistic people. M fires A for some made-up reason. By coincidence the owner of the company finds out, A is reinstated, and M gets fired.

A doesn’t want to sue the company, but is obviously unhappy about what M did. Is there anything that she could sue M personally for successfully? If not for the coincidence that the company owner found out just at the right time, A would have lost their job through illegal discrimination, so this would have been an attempt at illegal discrimination.

Comment: Where is Company located? The answer will vary from one jurisdiction to the next.

Comment: What remedy would A be asking the court to grant in their lawsuit? They already have their job restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

I know you have asked about whether A can "personally sue M." I present another alternative: a complaint to a human rights commission or tribunal.

In Canada and its provinces there are human rights commissions/tribunals established to vindicate the rights granted under [Canada's Human Rights Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/h-6/FullText.html) and similar provincial human rights statutes. M's actions appear to be prohibited discrimination under all of these statutes, even though A ultimately did not lose her job. M's actions are not merely an attempt at prohibited discrimination; they *are* prohibted discrimination. Whether M's actions and a connection to a "prohibited ground of discrimination" can be proven is a separate issue.

For example, under the Canadian Human Rights Act, it is a "discriminatory practice" to "harass an individual on a prohibited ground of discrimination" "in matters related to employment." Under the Ontario Human Rights Code, "Every person who is an employee has a right to freedom from harassment in the workplace... because of ... disability."

The [Canadian Human Rights Tribunal](https://www.chrt-tcdp.gc.ca/resources/guide-to-understanding-the-chrt-en.html) says (and I've highlighted a couple of the remedies that seem particuarly relevant to your hypothetical):

> If the Tribunal finds that a complaint of discrimination is eatablished, it can make an order against the person who engaged in the discriminatory practice. This order can include the following terms:
>
> - **cease the discriminatory practice and take measures to prevent the practice from occurring in the future** (see s. 53(2)(a) of the Act);
> - make available to the victim the rights, opportunities or privileges that were denied (see s. 53(2)(b) of the Act);
> - compensate the victim for any lost wages as a result of the discrimination (see s. 53(2)(c) of the Act);
> - compensate the victim for the additional costs of obtaining alternative goods, services, facilities or accommodation as a result of the discrimination (see s. 53(2)(d) of the Act);
> - compensate the victim up to $20,000 for any pain and suffering that the victim experienced as a result of the discrimination (see s. 53(2)(e) of the Act);
> - **compensate the victim up to $20,000 if the discrimination was wilful or reckless** (see s. 53(3) of the Act); and,
> - award interest on an order to pay financial compensation (see s. 53(4) of the Act).

Similar remedies are available in [British Columbia](http://www.bchrt.bc.ca/human-rights-duties/remedies/index.htm).

Comment: Thank you. To take away: 1. It's discrimination even if it fails. 2. A court could tell Manager M not to discriminate against people (presumably in other jobs) and take measures to avoid it. 3. In this case where the discrimination was fully intentional, M could be ordered to pay compensation to the victim. Proably without need for damages, because otherwise the bolded paragraph would be pointless.